# Google Glass stuck at "Complete action using"

Tags: android, apk, google-glass, android-launcher

I was fiddling around with custom launchers on the Google GLASS (Launchy) and got this screen after a reboot (`Complete action using...`):

[image: Complete action using]

Tapping the GLASS toggles the checkbox, but I can't get past this screen. I successfully uninstalled Launchy from an adb shell, but the problem persists. The device is also not rooted, and I need to keep it that way. ADB debugging is of course enabled.

- Because I'm not connected to a wifi network, I can't remotely factory restore the device
- The GLASS is paired with my phone via bluetooth, but attempting a factory restore through the "MyGlass" app is ineffective
- I can't wipe my userdata via fastboot, probably because I'm not rooted (`erasing 'userdata' FAILED (remote failure)`)
- Using my phone as a bluetooth keyboard was also ineffective

Any ideas? Anything goes so long as it doesn't void the warranty or risk a hard brick. Thanks.

Here are some related resources:

- [Glass & Launchy](http://www.reddit.com/r/googleglass/comments/1v5y0u/glass_launchy/)
- [XE12 broke launchy launching](https://github.com/kaze0/launchy/issues/17)
- [No way to factory reset Glass if an apk blocks access to Glass Home](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=198)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few things to try

1) double check that you really uninstalled launchy. You can get a list of all the installed packages with

```
adb shell pm list packages -f
```

if you downloaded any other launcher, that should also be removed.

2) try to bring up the home card with the following adb command:

```
adb shell am start -n com.google.glass.home/.timeline.MainTimelineActivity
```

If you can get that far, maybe you'll be able to connect to wifi and do a factory reset that way

3) use the third link you posted under related resources to get instructions on how to do a factory reset from fastboot.

Comment: Wiping userdata with `fastboot -w` is apparently the equivalent of a factory reset, which unfortunately didn't work as I specified. The `-f` parameter was the key. Some 3rd party "Launcher2" and "Settings" apps were named `com.android.launcher` and `com.android.settings` (These sounded important). With the -f flag, their apk names were in the form `com.android.settings-2.apk` (giveaway). Everything's back to normal after uninstalling them. Thanks!!

Comment: fix worked, 
adb uninstall com.android.launcher

Wish it wasn't named by that convention. I thought that was native GDK